# Median of the set of numbers which consists of all positive integers whose digits strictly increase from left to right

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the set
$$S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,23,24,\ldots,123456789\},$$
which consists of all positive integers whose digits strictly increase from left to right. This set is finite. What is the median of the set?

This problem is harder than I thought at first. I first simply though the solution was $\frac{123456789+1}{2}=61728395.$ Turns out I'm wrong! Where am I going wrong? I checked my work and $61728395-1+1=61728395.$ 
Also,

$123456789-61728395+1=61728395.$ These are equal, so the distance should also be equal. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why would it be $(123456789+1)/2$? Do you know what a median is?

Comment: It’s easier for the digits to be strictly increasing when the number has fewer digits, so numbers with strictly increasing digits become sparser as the numbers get bigger. This means that the median — the point that splits the set in half — will be less than the midpoint of the size range.

Comment: hmm, oh. Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Notice that $61728395\notin S$.

Comment: Well the median need not be an element of the set @AndrewChin

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A009993](https://oeis.org/A009993).

Comment: I suppose you're right, but if the set has an odd number of elements, then it must.  How many elements are in $S$?

Comment: Still not sure how to go with this problem. Does it have anything to do with one-to-one correspondence?

Comment: Suppose that we limit ourselves to two digit numbers. There are $9$ one-digit numbers in $S$ and $36$ two-digit numbers in $S$, for a total of $45$ numbers. The median is the $23$-rd number from the bottom (or top), which is $28$; this is a lot less than $\frac{1+89}2=45$.

Comment: @Bongocat - it seems like your confusion lies in the fact that there aren't 123456789 numbers in your set. Let's just take the numbers in this set that are less than 100 (say). How many are there? How can you (1) count how many there are, and then (2) identify the middle number?

Comment: @The Chaz 2.0, normally, I would use the formula $n-m+1$ where $n$ is the last number of the set, and $m$ is the first. For the middle number, I would use $(n+m)/2.$ I see that this is not the case, though. Let me read through some of the posts and see why.

Comment: There is an obvious one-to-one correspondence between this set and the set of all non-empty subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}.$ There are $2^{10}-1$ such subsets. Therefore the median is the $2^9\text{th}$ one from the bottom, which is also the $2^9\text{th}$ one from the top, i.e. the $512\text{th}$ one.

The smallest ones are the $1$-digit numbers, of which there are $\tbinom{10}1=10.$

Then there are the $2$-digit numbers, of which there are $\tbinom{10}2=45.$

And so on. $\qquad$

Comment: Think about row $10$ of Pascal's triangle:
$$
\require{cancel}
\xcancel1 \quad 10\quad45\quad120\quad210\quad 252\quad210\quad120\quad45\quad10\quad1
$$
We exclude the first one because there are no $0$-digit numbers. The $512\text{th}$ one is the $127\text{th}$ among the $252$ five-digit numbers.

Comment: Typo: $9,$ not $10.\qquad$

Comment: So you meant $2^9-1$ subsets, right?

Comment: @Bongocat : Yes.

Comment: Ok. Let me thouroughly review your advice. Thank you for helping. If you submitted it as a solution, I would definitely give +1

Comment: @Bongocat - you are really stuck on that formula, but that is only if EVERY NUMBER between m and n is included! This set has a LOT of gaps. So yes, if you were counting *the number of pages you read in a book from page 219 to page 234, you would subtract those numbers and add 1.* But if the book doesn't have all the pages...!

Comment: @The Chaz 2.0, got it. Can't rely on one formula for everything. Is there a way to determine if a set has gaps or not?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are 9 of these numbers having 1 digit, $\binom{9}{2}$ having 2 digits, and in general $\binom{9}{k}$ having $k$ digits.  The total number of elements in this set is thus $\binom{9}{1} + \binom{9}{2} + \cdots + \binom{9}{9} = 2^9-1$, by the binomial theorem, so the median is the $2^8$-th element.

The binomial theorem and symmetry of binomial coefficients also tells us $$\binom{9}{0} + \binom{9}{1} + \binom{9}{2} + \binom{9}{3} + \binom{9}{4} = \binom{9}{5} + \binom{9}{6} + \binom{9}{7} + \binom{9}{8} + \binom{9}{9} = 2^8$$

Hence $\binom{9}{1} + \binom{9}{2} + \binom{9}{3} + \binom{9}{4} = 2^8-1$.  So the median is the first element having 5 digits, which is $12345$.

Comment: As an aside, this problem generalizes nicely to any base number system.  In base $d$, if $d$ is even, the median is $123\dots\frac{d}{2}$.  If $d$ is odd, then the median is $234\dots\frac{d+1}{2}$.  Proving the latter is a bit more involved (Hockey Stick Identity).